# How to program a function that compares values in a list of list with extra condition when some of the values are none datatype

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, nonetype

I want to program a function that compares the values in a list of list with extra condition that when there is a "None" in the list, that particular element always "matches". v_ins and r_ins are the list of lists. `v_ins` may have a `None` in it but `r_ins` will always have integers in it.

I have tried the following code. I do not know what to do after the "elif". Also the lists will only have values in the first list in the list (eg. `v_ins = [[1,None,1]]`, but it will never be something like `v_ins = [[1,None][None,0]]` )

```
def comparestates():
    global v_ins,  r_ins
    if v_ins == r_ins:
        print ("state match")
    elif for j in range (0,len(v_ins[0])):
        "dont know what should come here"
        print ("state match")

v_ins = [[1,None,1]]
r_ins = [[1,0,1]]

comparestates()
```

The expected result is "state match" printed because the "None" in the second element of v_ins means it will always "match" with the second element of the r_ins.

Comment: `elif for j in range (0,len(v_ins[0]))` is a syntax error

Comment: Do you mean 'None' matches with any integers? (so [[1,None,1]] and [[1,99,1]] match?)

Comment: You're right. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: Yes.  'None' matches with any integers.  (so [[1,None,1]] and [[1,99,1]] match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that v_ins and r_ins have only one list element.

```
def compare(v, r):
    if len(v) != len(r):
        return False
    for i, j in zip(v, r):
        if i is not None and i != j:
            return False
    return True

def comparestates():
    global v_ins, r_ins
    if compare(v_ins[0], r_ins[0]):
        print("state match")
    else:
        print("no match")

v_ins = [[1,None,1]]
r_ins = [[1,0,1]]

comparestates()
```